# android button in listview both clickable

Tags: android, button, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a list view. In the layout of each row for the listview I have a button. That button in the xml has a "android:onClick="onClickDoSmth" " . The list view also has an itemClickListener.

In the Activity class I have a method "public void onClickDoSmth( View v) " which is called when the button is hit.

But I have also setup an ItemClickListener for the list view. I want when the row (outside of the button) is hit to go to another activity. When the button is visible the ItemClickListener for the listview does not work. When the button is View.GONE then the listview's listener works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Use ImageView instead of Button**. Both button click and OnItemClickListener don't work together.

Here is a working sample:

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView customLV;
    private CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
    String strArray[] = { "First", "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Fifth" };
    ArrayList<String> strAL = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strArray));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        customLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customLV);
        adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, strAL);
        customLV.setAdapter(adapter);
        customLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

CustomArrayAdapter.java

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> strAL) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, strAL);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.titleTV = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.titleTV);
            viewHolder.testBT = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.testBT);
            viewHolder.testBT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.titleTV.setText(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTV;
        ImageView testBT;

    }
}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testBT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/customLV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` as property for your `Button`. Then you should able to manage both `onClickDoSmth`/`onListItemClick` or `itemClickListener`